# What algorithm could I use to find the largest set of disjoint members from a set of subsets of a set?

Tags: algorithms, sets

I've written a political quiz based on data from [the public whip](http://www.publicwhip.org.uk).  They group politicians' votes by policy; each vote can belong to many policies.  There are too many policies for me to ask a question for each one, and anyway some are duplicates and some policies' votes are subsets of other policies.  In the past, I've manually chosen a subset of policies to use in my quiz try to maximise the number of votes included without double-counting any, but I'm worried that that may introduce my biases into what is supposed to be as neutral as possible a quiz.  So I'd like to find the set of policies which maximises the number of votes included without counting any of them twice.

Is there a known algorithm I could use to do this?  I've seen similar questions elsewhere on this site but they generally seem to involve sets of intervals or geometric shapes.

Comment: Your problem is NP-hard, by reduction from independent set (represent each vertex by the set of edges incident to it). You can try the greedy heuristic.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe is known as [set packing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing), and it has a natural ILP formulation. You can start with some ILP solver you have access to, and it should be a highly competitive solution. There are many heuristics to choose from as well if you don't require optimal solutions.